# Signed Applet throws AccessControlException when doing XSLT with external document()

Tags: debugging, xslt, applet, code-signing, accesscontrolexception

I would like to get help on signed applet + XSL transformation

I have a **signed** applet (with 1 JAR file) that performs XSL transformation where the input XML, the XSL and the output is read/written on the local file system.
I have already tried it with JRE

- 1.5.0_22
- 1.6.0_29
- 1.7.0_01

and the result is the same:

When my XSL file contains a reference to an external XML document:

```
<xsl:variable name="extXML" select="document('/tmp/A.XML')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$extXML/Child"/>
```

the transformation fails:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.TransletException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission /tmp/A.XML read)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.LoadDocument.documentF(LoadDocument.java:142)
at in.topLevel()
at in.transform()
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.AbstractTranslet.transform(AbstractTranslet.java:603)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:709)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:313)
at myxsltapplet.MyXSLTApplet.xsltTransform(MyXSLTApplet.java:66)
```

If this reference to external XML document is commented out everything work just fine.
Using a policy file solves this problem but unfortunately this is not an option.

I have implemented a [URIResolver](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/URIResolver.html) that I set for the [TransformerFactory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#setURIResolver%28javax.xml.transform.URIResolver%29) but I also get AccessControlException in it.

In the applet I have retrieved the [SecurityManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) and its [AccessControlContext](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/AccessControlContext.html) and logged out their hashcode:

```
SecurityManager: sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2SecurityManager@103fcaa
getSecurityContext(): java.security.AccessControlContext@17b2b2
```

I did the same in my URIResolver implementation and the AccessControlContext has changed:

```
SecurityManager: sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2SecurityManager@103fcaa
getSecurityContext(): java.security.AccessControlContext@ede64c
```

Calling checkPermission on the original AccessControlContext runs without exception.

Calling checkPermission on the new AccessControlContext accessible in my URIResolver:

```
AccessControlContext acc = (AccessControlContext) System.getSecurityManager().getSecurityContext();
acc.checkPermission(new FilePermission("/tmp/A.XML", "read"));
```

throws:

```
ERROR: 'java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission /tmp/A.XML read)'
```

Is it a normal thing or a bug?
Thanks for any idea,

Comment: Can a standard application read that input file?  What about the system default consumer for the file?

Comment: Yes. If the reference to the external XML document is removed the transformation works.

Comment: Is the functionality called using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Software that runs in the browser is normally prevented from accessing local files. Here are some explanations of why:

- [Why is my applet throwing an AccessControlException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568345/why-is-my-applet-throwing-an-accesscontrolexception?rq=1)